# Phone_info matching query does not exist

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

views.py

```
def add_phone(request):
    user=request.user
    try:
        phone = Phone_info.objects.get(user=user.id)
    except Phone_info.DoesNotExist:
        phone = None
    phoneForm = PhoneForm({'user':request.user})
    phone = Phone_info.objects.get(user=request.user)
    phoneForm = PhoneForm(instance=phone)
    if request.method=='POST':
        phoneForm = PhoneForm(request.POST,instance=phone)
        if phoneForm.is_valid():
            phone=phoneForm.save(commit=False)
            phone.save()
            return redirect('/member/contact-list/')

    return render_to_response('incident/add_phone.html',
    {
    'about_menu': True,
    'PhoneForm' :phoneForm
    },
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

models.py is

```
class Phone_info(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    name1 = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    number1 = models.CharField('Number',max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    name2 =  models.CharField('Name', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    number2 = models.CharField('Number', max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
```

Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://192.168.100.10/member/add-phone/

Django Version: 1.3.7
Python Version: 2.7.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'south',
 'collect',
 'incident']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware')
```

Edit:

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/root/Projects/ir/incident/views.py" in add_phone
  648.     phone = Phone_info.objects.get(user=request.user)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in get
  132.         return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  349.                     % self.model._meta.object_name)

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /member/add-phone/
Exception Value: Phone_info matching query does not exist.
```

I am not able to insert or update data into the database,getting the following error"`Phone_info matching query does not exist"`

Can any one suggest me what went wrong here.
Edit:I updsated the traceback.The error is in 6th line.Any idea what would be the problem.

Comment: I updated my views.py with updated code.Same problem comes again

Comment: Are you sure the data exists with the current user's id as foreign key?

Comment: Bibhas,user is foreign key

Comment: I'm asking if you're sure that the data exists at the first place. can you show it?

Comment: No data not exist.I am coding the above views for inserting data if data not exist in db for that user.If data already exist,should be able to edit.I am learning django,so not much familiar about the programming.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Model_name> matching query does not exist` means what it exactly reads. The record you're looking for, doesn't exist. So, make sure that the data exists at the first place.

And you code also has come loose ends -

```
user=request.user
try:
    # This line is generating error because record doesn't exists[1]
    phone = Phone_info.objects.get(user=user.id)
except Phone_info.DoesNotExist:
    phone = None
phoneForm = PhoneForm({'user':request.user})
# You're making the same query as [1] here, knowing that it might not exist. Redundant, illogical.
phone = Phone_info.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

I'm assured that you are new with django, but saying that every time doesn't help things. Get your logic right. Try to `get()`, if there is exception, create record. You're initiating your `PhoneForm` thrice. Data gets overwritten. Fix that.

Django has one of the most comprehensive documentation. [Go through it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/).

PS: Just as a bonus hint, get your coding convention right. At one place you're querying `Phone_info.objects.get(user=user.id)` where you just assigned `user = request.user`, right next to it, you're querying `Phone_info.objects.get(user=request.user)`. Not just you just broke your convention of using `id` to query, from the earlier line, you just used `request.user` again, although you have a variable where it's assigned. While *both queries will work*, but it's necessary that you follow a convention when you write code, makes it much more debuggable later on.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show your traceback, so we have no idea where your error is coming from.

However I will point out that you have an error in the second line: `user` isn't defined, so `user.id` will always fail. You probably meant `request.user.id`. Of course, you've caught and hidden **all** errors in that try/except statement, so you'd **never know** there was a name error. Don't ever, ever do that. Catch the errors that you know will be raised: in this case, it's `User.DoesNotExist`.

Comment: Sigh. I didn't notice that line, it obviously makes the definition of `phone` inside that try/except completely pointless. And I don't understand what you don't understand: there *isn't* a Phone_info for the current user. That error message is perfectly clear. What are you having problems with?

Comment: First of all, fix those two problems I noted. Then, try to use some logic to solve the remaining issue yourself. If you can't, then post your updated code and explain exactly what you are having problems with.